# A simplistic blogging CMS for my needs?

Tags: content-management-system, blogs

I'm looking for a CMS which isn't too feature heavy and simply allows me to post, users to comment and to login. I'd like to embed it easily inside a HTML/CSS website I've already built too. Opinions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simple without requiring with PHP/MySQL I'd look at TiddlyWiki: http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

I've only played with it briefly in the past but it's nice and simple to install. It's all contained in one file that you put on your server. It has a dedicated fan base and although it's called a wiki it's also good as a blogging platform or basic CMS.